# Find a Maclaurin series for a sum of two functions

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I have the following homework question

Find the Maclaurin series for $f(x) = (x^3+x)\sin x$ and use it to find $f^{(n)}(0)$.

What I did is the following $$f(x)=x^3\sin x+x\sin x$$ which equals to $$f(x)=x^3\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}+x\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$ so $f(x)$ would be $$f(x) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+4}}{(2n+1)!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+2}}{(2n+1)!}$$ and I know that $f^{(n)}(0)$ would be the coefficient of $\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$ but I'm not sure if I have to combine these two sums to find it.

Comment: You’re doing it exactly right. Reindex one of the sums if you want to combine them.

Comment: Reindexing just lets you combine coefficients formally. For example, replace $n$ with $n-1$ in the first sum, and then let $n$ run from $1$ to $\infty$. Then the generic term is $\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n+2}}{(2n-1)!}$, so now both sums have the same power of $x$ in the generic term. The tradeoff is that you have to pull the first term out of the second sum, @AndrewLi .

Comment: That’s no good. You want to combine terms that have the same power of $x$. That’s the point of reindexing one of them, @AndrewLi

Comment: OP’s final sentence is spot-on.

Comment: @MPW Oh my bad, I completely had a brain fart. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to combine the two series $$f(x) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+4}}{(2n+1)!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+2}}{(2n+1)!}$$

The coefficient of $x^n$ will be, $$ a_n=0 \text { for } n=2k+1$$ and $$a_n = (-1)^{n/2} \big( \frac {1}{(n-3)!} - \frac {1}{(n-1)!} \big)$$  for $ n=2k.$

$$ f(x) = x^2 + (1- 1/{3!})x^4 -( 1/{3!}- 1/{5!})x^6+....$$